# How to link to the WordPress plugins folder from style.css?

Tags: css, wordpress, relative-path

I'm trying to link to an image in the WordPress plugins folder from style.css. I've tried the following but that doesn't work:

```
.example {
    background: url( images/photo.jpg ) center center no-repeat;
}
```

**Plugins folder image:** /wp-content/plugins/my-plugin/images/photo.jpg

**Stylesheet is here:** /wp-content/themes/my-theme/style.css

Comment: add css and image in your plugin folder get this using plugin url.

Comment: I'd prefer not to have lots of CSS files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know you added the "relative-path" tag, but have you tried using an absolute path, including the domain name?

Consider trying

```
.example {
    background: url('http://full-path.com/wp-content/plugins/my-plugin/images/photo.jpg') center center no-repeat;
}
```

If you want to use a relative path, it also looks like you could try:

```
../../plugins/my-plugin/images/photo.jpg
```

This assumes the server is looking from the folder the CSS is in to resolve the path to the photo. The ".." represents moving up a directory level.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

You can use so called semi-relative paths for resources:

```
.example {
    background-image: url( '/wp-content/plugins/path/to/image.jpg' );
}
```

`/wp-content/` above maps to `http://www.domain.xyz/wp-content/`, which allows you to omit the  domain portion from the URL path to the image. If you omit the starting `/` character, the stylesheet will look for `wp-content/...` within the directory where the CSS file is.

> Note: the above method wont work if your plugins directory is outside `wp-content`.

If you want the exact plugin directory path using WordPress functions and constants, consider infusing CSS with PHP: http://css-tricks.com/css-variables-with-php/. This way you can execute some PHP within the CSS file, which could include fetching the WP plugins directory to a PHP variable.